# How to update state of parent widget from child widget and reflect it in child widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have parent stateful widget which has button on tap of which I show a bottom sheet in which I have dropdown menu. now the state variable, list and function all are in the parent widget when choose any option in drop down it call the function to set that variable to new value but it doesn't reflect on the screen. when `pop` the bottom sheet and open it again it shows the `updated` value.

parent,

```
class PageAssets extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageAssetsState createState() => _PageAssetsState();
}

class _PageAssetsState extends State<PageAssets> {
OrganisationModel selectedOrganisation; //-----> state variable 
 List<OrganisationModel> lstOrganisation = []; //----> list of values

selectedOrgChanged(OrganisationModel plant) { //----> function which is to call on change 
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        selectedOrganisation = plant;
      });
    }
    loadPlants(plant: selectedOrganisation);
  }

//somewhere in UI
...
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.tune),
              onPressed: () async {
                  showModalBottomSheet();
          })

}
```

custom drop down button

```
FilterDropDown(
                      title: 'Organization',
                      onOrgChange: (val) {
                        widget.selectedOrgChanged(val);
                      },
                      orgList: widget.lstOrganisation,
                      selectedOrg: widget.selectedOrganisation,
                    )
```

custom dropdown menu

```
class FilterDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final OrgBase selectedOrg;
  final List<OrgBase> orgList;
  final OnOrgChange onOrgChange;
  final String title;

  FilterDropDown({
    this.title,
    this.orgList,
    this.selectedOrg,
    this.onOrgChange,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 130,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 55,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7, vertical: 2),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffe4e4eb),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: DropdownButton<OrgBase>(
              isExpanded: true,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
              iconSize: 30,
              hint: Text('--Choose--'),
              underline: SizedBox(),
              value: selectedOrg,
              items: orgList
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<OrgBase>>(
                      (value) => DropdownMenuItem<OrgBase>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(
                            value.label,
                            style: theme.textTheme.subtitle1,
                          )))
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: onOrgChange),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

so how can I fix this?

Comment: are you missing `setState` on ` widget.selectedOrgChanged(val);` ? , the way i handle this thing using `globalKey` or `stateManagement` like using `riverpod`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh `widget.selectedOrgChanged(val);` is the function from parent which is shown in the code which has the `setState` and after you told me I tried adding it also but doesn't work. using state management I can do that but this is old project and I have to do this with stateful widget

Comment: oh sorry, can you check `loadPlants` method on parent widget.

Comment: `loadPlants` is to actually update another list and it does have `setState` I just want to update the dropdown menu which is not updating other then that everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

inside `FilterDropDown` on `DropdownButton` ,

replace  `onChanged: onOrgChange,`
with
 `onChanged: (value) => onOrgChange(value),`

Comment: hey @Yeasin Sheikh thank you for sticking around but this I already tried and I just found the solution I needed to use the `StatefulBuilder` on top of bottom sheet and use the it's void function to set the state